# how to redirect https://www.example.com to https://example.com with .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

[www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will redirected to https://example.com.

https://www.example.com will not redirected to https://example.com. How to do this?

The current rules looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z0-9-]+\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z0-9-]+\.[NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:[a-z0-9-]+\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Do you specifically need a generic "any domain" version? Why not hardcode the canonical hostname? (This would generally be more reliable.)

Comment: I could. But what´s the advantage to do so?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[a-z0-9-]+\.[NC]
> ```

You are missing a space before the flags argument, so it becomes part of the *CondPattern* and it never matches, so the second redirect block (from HTTPS) never happens.

However, this should still be caught by the first rule block, but... this looks like it would create a small redirect loop since the regex `^[a-z0-9-]+\.` matches `www.`, but it would also match `example.` (after the first redirect). Potentially redirecting to `https://com/foo`!?

You don't need both rules.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing. (Test with 302 to avoid caching issues.)

> But what´s the advantage to do so?

In hardcoding the canonical hostname... it depends on whether you have other subdomains or domains pointing to the same account.

A hardcoded solution is simpler, less prone to error and generally more reliable.

Comment: Ok. I thought so. I haven´t other subdomains. Thanks so far. In my browser at the pc it works but not at my smartphone... Its an old smartphone with an old browser but that´s not the point, right?

Comment: How "old"? Which browser? Make sure you've cleared your browser cache - that's the most probable cause. Unless redirects are actually disabled in the browser (unlikely). The redirect above is entirely server-side. The browser only needs to respond to a 3xx response.